# Pythonic Way to Initialize (Complex) Static Data Members

Tags: python, class

I have a class with a complex data member that I want to keep "static". I want to initialize it once, using a function. How Pythonic is something like this:

```
def generate_data():
    ... do some analysis and return complex object e.g. list ...

class Coo:
    data_member = generate_data()
    ... rest of class code ...
```

The function `generate_data` takes a long while to complete and returns data that remains constant in the scope of a running program. I don't want it to run every time class Coo is instantiated.

Also, to verify, as long as I don't assign anything to `data_member` in `__init__`, it will remain "static"? What if a method in Coo appends some value to `data_member` (assuming it's a list) - will this addition be available to the rest of the instances?

Thanks

Comment: The only thing un-Pythonic about that code is using a lowercase identifier for a class name.

Comment: @Card: Of course you are right, I changed it :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're right on all counts.  `data_member` will be created once, and will be available to all instances of `coo`.  If any instance modifies it, that modification will be visible to all other instances.

Here's an example that demonstrates all this, with its output shown at the end:

```
def generate_data():
    print "Generating"
    return [1,2,3]

class coo:
    data_member = generate_data()
    def modify(self):
        self.data_member.append(4)

    def display(self):
        print self.data_member

x = coo()
y = coo()
y.modify()
x.display()

# Output:
# Generating
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: What about anything outside of the class?

Comment: @Omega: It's the same - just say "module_data = generate_data()" at module scope.

Answer (score 13):

As others have answered you're right -- I'll add one more thing to be aware of: If an instance modifies the object `coo.data_member` itself, for example

```
self.data_member.append('foo')
```

then the modification is seen by the rest of the instances. However if you do

```
self.data_member = new_object
```

then a new *instance* member is created which overrides the class member and is only visible to that instance, not the others. The difference is not always easy to spot, for example `self.data_member += 'foo'` vs. `self.data_member = self.data_member + 'foo'`.

To avoid this you probably should always refer to the object as `coo.data_member` (not through `self`).

Comment: +1 several good points, especially about referencing as a class attribute instead of a instance attribute.

Answer (score 6):

The statement `data_member = generate_data()` will be executed only once, when `class coo: ...` is executed. In majority of cases class statements occur at module level and are executed when module is imported. So `data_member = generate_data()` will be executed only once when you import module with class `coo` for the first time.

All instances of `coo` class will share `data_member` and can access it by writing `coo.data_member`. Any changes made to `coo.data_member` will be immediately visible by any `coo` instance. An instance can have its own `data_member` attribute. This attribute can be set by typing `self.data_member = ...` and will be visible only to that instance. The "static" `data_member` can still be accessed by typing `coo.data_member`.